# How do I add a UTC offset from the local time?

Tags: javascript

This is the code, I am trying to make a HTML display for UTC+8 but I am in ITC

```
setInterval(function(){
  var dt = new Date();
  document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you get and what you want?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: @phuzi im trying to make a html page to display the time, but i am in utc+0, trying to have it so it displays utc+8.

Comment: Do you want to show the current time in a different timezone? If yes, which timezone in particular?

Comment: @phuzi UTC+8 I want to show the current time in a different time zone

Comment: UTC+8 is only an offset - it may be different throughout the year due to daylight savings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```js
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'};
    
function getUTCDate(offset)
{
  var Now = new Date();
  var UTCDate = new Date(Now.getTime() + Now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);; // UTC Date
  // Get difference in Timezone (offset => to Difference)
  var tzDifference = UTCDate.getTimezoneOffset() + (offset * 60 * 60);
  var offsetTime = new Date(UTCDate.getTime() + (offset * 60 * 60) * 1000);
  return (offsetTime.toLocaleDateString("en-EN", options) + " (UTC" + (offset > 0 ? "+" : "") + (offset != 0 ? offset : "") + ")")
}

setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = getUTCDate(+8);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: thank you so so much!!

Comment: Glad to help, I just updated now to fix a bug, get the newest one. If this is the answer you are looking for, can you mark it as correct?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can use toUTCString method.

```
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toUTCString();
```

Comment: Hi, trying to make it so it displays another timezone instead of UTC. It gets my local time, but I'm trying to make it display UTC+8 instead. Not needing to get the UTC of my current timezone, but thanks :D

Comment: @flutters Can you show us an example of what you're getting and what you want.